# Probability of at least 1 of multiple, distinct marbles from a bag (with replacement)

Tags: probability

I am considering a problem where the goal is to calculate the expected number of marbles pulls required to get *at least* 1 of each rare marble color (with replacement). I.e. in a bag of 512 marbles I have 1 red, 1 green, 3 purple, and 507 white. I know that individually, the expected value to pull a red is 512. But I do not understand how to calculate the expected value of pulling at least 1 red, green, and purple.

Comment: Well, work from states.  You only have a few states, according to which rare colors have been seen.  Thus, $\emptyset, R, G, P,RG, PG, RP, RGP$.  Symmetry helps....since you have one each of $R, G$ we know that the expected number of tosses from State $R$ is the same as it is from $G$ and so on.

Comment: Have you heard of a "Markov Chain"?  Have you considered describing this as a markov chain with $8$ (*or fewer if clever*) states?  (*red found, green found, purple found  vs  red missing, green found, purple found  vs  red found, green missing, purple found vs ... vs red missing, green missing, purple missing*)

Comment: @JMoravitz i have heard of markov chains but don't know anything about them, how should i go about this problem using them?